# How would I go about plotting this kmeans cluster in R

Tags: r

Here is the code I'm using to do kmeans clustering:

```
library(cluster)
data(USArrests)
kmeans(USArrests,centers=4,algorithm=c("Hartigan-Wong"),iter.max=100,nstart=20)
```

Comment: That depends on what you mean by plot. What kind of visual are you looking for? What have you tried?

Comment: Why just one cluster?  That does not seem very useful.

Comment: Sorry, the number of clusters was supposed to be four, and i'm looking to visualize the data in the best way possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see how the data was classified, I'd do something like this:

```
model=kmeans(USArrests,centers=4,algorithm=c("Hartigan-Wong"),iter.max=100,nstart=20)
ggplot(USArrests,aes(x=Murder,y=Assault))+geom_point(color=model$cluster)
```

The problem is that you'd be plotting two variables while the data was classified with 4.

Hope that helps.